# RegEx: Grabbing paragraphs in markdown

Tags: regex

I have a markdown file and want to grap the whole text between the first two subheadlines with line breakings and other subsubheadlines.

This is the given markdown

```
# main stuff

random text

## sub stuff


### subsub stuff

* bla bla
* bla bla


### subsub2

* **bold stuff:** blabla ([#11](https://blalba)) 
* **bold stuff:** blabla ([#11](https://blalba)) 
* **bold stuff:** blabla ([#11](https://blalba)) 


## sub staff 2

### subsub

* blaa
* blaa

## sub staff 3

### blaaa

* blubb
* **bold stuff:** blabla ([#11](https://blalba)) 

## sub staff 4

### subsub

* blaa
* blaa


## sub staff 5

### blaaa

* blubb
```

I want the part between the first two `##`. So in this example I want the following:

```
## sub stuff


### subsub stuff

* bla bla
* bla bla


### subsub2

* **bold stuff:** blabla ([#11](https://blalba)) 
* **bold stuff:** blabla ([#11](https://blalba)) 
* **bold stuff:** blabla ([#11](https://blalba))
```

What I tried

1. `## ([^## ]*)##` but this does not contain the line breaks
2. `## [\s\S]*##` but this contains all characters until the last `##` in the file

I need a combination something like `## ([\s\S^## ]*)##`, but yes, this is not valid in the way I need it.

Comment: Use `## [\s\S]*?##` if you need to get to the first `##` after `##` + space

Comment: That's not working. It stops at the first wordgroup `## `, and this is directly in the next line. See https://regexr.com/54l7f

Comment: `## [\s\S]*?(?=\s*\n## |$(?![\s\S]))`? Are you coding in JS?

Comment: This one works, thank you :) 
I use it in the bash, not JS.

Comment: Bash regex does not support lookaheads and shorthands are not supported inside bracket expressions. Or do you mean you are using `grep` with`-P` option?

Comment: I see... That was the idea, to read the markdown file and use `grep` with an regex to print out the matched part.

Comment: Ok, you will need `grep -Poz '(?s)## .*?(?=\s*\n## |$)' file`. Try, and if it works, I will post with explanations.

Comment: does not work on my mac terminal  argument `P` and `z` is unknown

Comment: Install `pcregrep` and use `pcregrep -oM 'pattern' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may use

```
(?s)## .*?(?=\s*\n## |$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CJDSAU/1)

The pattern matches

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL modifier that makes `.` match line break chars
- `##`   - a literal string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*\n## |$)` - a location that is immediately followed with 0+ whitespaces, newline, and then `##` , or the end of the string.